# Android fragment manager fragment change listener

Tags: android

When replacing a fragment using a `FragmentManager` is it possible to add a listener for when the event is completed?

So

```
myFragmentManager
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment, FRAGMENT_TAG)
            .commit()
```

can I add a listener to `myFragmentManager` so that I know when the fragment has been replaced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement following listener in your activity class to watch for changes to the fragment back stack.

```
public static interface FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener
```

later you need to register this listener to the fragment manager with the help of

```
 addOnBackStackChangedListener (FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener listener)
```

**Links for your reference**

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager#addonbackstackchangedlistener

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener

Comment: This won't be called unless the fragment is added to the backstack, and so won't work with the OP's example

Answer (score 28):

`FragmentManager (android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager)` has a nice method called `registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks` which helps register a `FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks`. This allows us to take actions during the fragment's life cycle. You can do something in `onFragmentCreated()` as you wish.

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onFragmentPreAttached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Context context) {
                super.onFragmentPreAttached(fm, f, context);
                Log.v("FragXX1", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentAttached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Context context) {
                super.onFragmentAttached(fm, f, context);
                Log.v("FragXX2", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onFragmentCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState);
                Log.v("FragXX3", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentActivityCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onFragmentActivityCreated(fm, f, savedInstanceState);
                Log.v("FragXX4", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentViewCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onFragmentViewCreated(fm, f, v, savedInstanceState);
                Log.v("FragXX5", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentStarted(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentStarted(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX6", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentResumed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentResumed(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX7", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentPaused(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentPaused(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX8", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentStopped(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentStopped(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX9", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentSaveInstanceState(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f, Bundle outState) {
                super.onFragmentSaveInstanceState(fm, f, outState);
                Log.v("FragXX10", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentViewDestroyed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentViewDestroyed(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX11", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentDestroyed(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentDestroyed(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX12", f.getTag());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFragmentDetached(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f) {
                super.onFragmentDetached(fm, f);
                Log.v("FragXX13", f.getTag());
            }
        }, true);

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.container, new TradeFragment(), "trien");
        ft.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your new `Fragment`'s `onResume` function is launched when the new `Fragment` is active. You can do what you want to do when the previous `Fragment` is replaced in it.